# Formatting LocalTime Minutes/Seconds into Integer Java

Tags: java, formatting, localtime

I know there are similar questions but they don't answer my problem. I want to format the current time into integer, but only the minutes or seconds.

So for example

```
LocalTime d = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
```

gives me the current GMT and with "withNano(0)" I can cut off the nanoseconds. Since I have it in the format 12:15:45 now I want to be able to save 15 (Minutes) into my Integer or 45 (Seconds). How can I convert it?

Comment: Usage: that conversion is not a formatting.

Comment: xiaofeng - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 4):

You can call specific methods on the `LocalTime` such as `getMinute()` and `getSecond()`, or you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` with a pattern that you’re looking for, like:

```
d.format(DateTimeFormatter.of(“mm:ss”);
```

If you’re doing that, you don’t need to zero out the nano first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built in methods for getting minutes and seconds, they both return integers:

```
     d.getMinute();
     d.getSecond();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the getter methods of `LocalTime`.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        int hour = now.getHour();
        int minute = now.getMinute();
        int second = now.getSecond();
        System.out.printf("%d hour, %d minute, %d second", hour, minute, second);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
21 hour, 37 minute, 47 second
```

Also, I suggest you use `ZoneOffset.UTC` for `UTC` instead of the 3-letter name for timezone. You can also use `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")`. The general naming convention for timezone is `Region/City` e.g. `Europe/London`.